# In ES6 Can we refer to JS variables in HTML using { }

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a variable in my Javascript Module called `test`

```
const test = 'abc';
```

Now can I use `{test}` to refer to test in my html code. Or do I always have to get the html tag by document.... and them setInnerHTML to it. I would prefer if someone could give an elaborate answer to referring variables of ES6 inside HTML.

Thank you

Comment: ES6 has absolutely nothing to do with HTML, so the elaborate answer is "no".

Comment: Do you mean the `template strings` where you can use variables like this: `\`my super cool string ${test}\``

Comment: [I guess you mean something like Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: Yes I see template strings in es6 the way we use them in reactjs but my question was really to see if there was a replacement for document.......setInnerHTML

Comment: If you want to do this with less code you can use `jquery`

Answer (score 2):

HTML can include JavaScript only in `<script>` elements and intrinsic event attributes.

New versions of JavaScript do not and cannot change this. (Since it is a (non-)feature of HTML, not of JS).

The syntax you describe is used by a number of template languages, such as [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) and [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/), along with things that are not-quite-templates like [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html). It is not HTML.

Comment: I was coming from the perspective of using {} in reactjs jsx :)